# Rails - route redirect based on Route Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Currently, if I want to redirect to certain page, I must use `to: redirect('/this-is-some-url')` ..

I wondering if I can redirect to a certain page using `Route Name` such as `to: redirect('route_name')`

I try below code, but it's not working:

```
get '/house-url', to: redirect('home')          #the value is route name
get '/home-url', to: 'home_ctrl#show', as: 'home'
```

Comment: I post an answer, but if someone find an other way, I will be really interessed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redirect with the url path but not with the name of your route.

```
get '/house-url', to: redirect('/home-url')
```

> Redirect any path to another path

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html

### Edit

I find a better way :

**1. Create RedirectToHome**

Create a class named `RedirectToHome` (in file `redirect_to_home.rb`).

You can create this for exemple in your `app/controllers/`

```
class RedirectToHome
  def call(params, request)
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.home_path # this is the path where to redirect
  end
end
```

**2. Edit your route.rb**

And add the RedirectToHome to your route that you want to redirect

```
  get '/home-url', to: 'home_ctrl#show', as: 'home'
  get '/house-url' => redirect(RedirectToHome.new)
```

Comment: so there's no way to redirect to another path (based on the route name)??

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien I find a better way, check my edit. With RedirectToHome it works. Feel free to accept my answer if it works for you =)

Comment: looks complicated..but i think there is no other way except this...and it is actually works...thanks for your answer...

Comment: I agree, it's a little bit boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

So if i read your question correctly you want to pass the requested route to a redirect?

You can do something like this:

```rb
get '/houses/:house_id', to: redirect { |path_params, req| "/houses/#{path_params[:house_id]}" }
```